# Too early in the morning to have SODA?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers, alphametic

Each letter shown represent distinct digit...can vary from zero to nine.

$COCA$, $COLA$, $SODA$ are three concatenated numbers.

Figure these out from the following relation:

$COCA + COLA = SODA$

Comment: deleted image. feel free to rollback if needed :)

Comment: Am I the only one who thought "Too early in  the morning" was a hint?

Comment: I don’t know..when I got up little early yesterday, title popped in my head

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on Omega Krypton's answer,

> $2C+1=S,C+L=D+10$, $A=0,O=9$. (Note that $O=9$ so $C+L$ carries.)
>  We also need that these digits $C,L,D,S$ are **distinct** between $1\sim 8$. ($0$ and $9$ are taken.) 
>  If $C=1$ or $C=2$ then, since $D\ge 1$ we have $L\ge 9$ which is incorrect.
>  So $C=3$ and $S=7$. We have $L=8$ and $D=1$.
>  That is $3930+3980=7910$.

Comment: hi, nice try! +1

Comment: Got it!!....deceptively unique

Comment: Yeah *deceptively*. :)

Answer (score 19):

We have the following

```
 COCA
+COLA
-----
 SODA
```

> First, from the ones column, we have $A+A \implies A$ which is only possible if $A=0$.

Next, notice something similar in the

> hundreds place; $O+O \implies O$.  Since $0$ is already taken and the only possibility without a carry over, we must have a carry over from the 10s, and $O=9$ is the only possibility.  We will also have a carry over into the thousands.

Since we have a 4 digit number as the result, we know that

> $0 \lt C \le 4$.

But:

> -But $C=4 \implies S=9$ which is already taken by $O$.
>  -And $C=1 \implies L=9$ to achieve a carryover, which is taken by $O$.
>  -And $C=2 \implies L\in\{8,9\}$.  But $L=9$ is taken, and $L=8 \implies D=0$ is also taken.

Thus,

> $C=3$.

Also, we know

> $S=7$ because the hundreds will carry over, and we also know that in order to carry over the 10s, we need $L\ge 7$.  But $L=7$ and $L=9$ are taken leaving only $L=8$, and thus, $D=1$.

Thus, the solution is;

> COCA+COLA=SODA, 3930+3980=7910

Comment: Easiest deductions for me =)

Answer (score 8):

Since we know that

> $A+A \equiv A \pmod {10}$

Therefore $A$

> $=0$

Hundreds value must carry since $O \neq 0$

Therefore

> $O+O+1 \equiv O \pmod {10}$

Therefore $O$

> $=9$

We now get

> $2C+1=S$
>  $C+L=D$

And since $S<9$

> $0<C<4$

Then there are many possibilities... any relations I missed out?

Comment: On the right track..I think it is unique

Comment: Keep going..eventually you will get there